# Getting date format in C# identical to javascript date function

Tags: c#, javascript

I'm assigning the date to the variable in javascript.

```
var myDate = new Date(y, m, 1)
```

So I get the date in `myDate` as: `Fri Mar 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

I need to format the date string in C sharp in the same manner.

I tried something like this:

```
string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss} GMT {1}", dt.ToLocalTime(), dt.ToLocalTime().ToString("%K"))
```

It gives me: `"2013-03-12 01:31:49 GMT +05:30"`

So it's not the exact format I want. Any help...

Comment: I've updated my answer to give you the exact string that JavaScript gives you including the time zone information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the following which will give you exactly the same as JavaScript!

`string.Format("{0:ddd MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss \"GMT\"K} ({1})", dt.ToLocalTime(), TimeZoneInfo.Local.StandardName)`

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
System.DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss \"GMT\"K")
```

returns "Tue Mar 12 2013 14:01:38 GMT+05:30"

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a more proper way, but in this case the initial part of your format string is just off:

```
ddd MMM dd yyyy

string.Format("{0:ddd MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss} GMT {1}", dt.ToLocalTime(), dt.ToLocalTime().ToString("%K"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string.Format("{0:ddd MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss} GMT {1}", dt.ToLocalTime(), dt.ToLocalTime().ToString("%K"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You format string is wrong.
Should be something like:

```
"{0:ddd MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss} GMT{1}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use

```
dt.ToString("ddd MMM dd yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'K");
```

Should give you

```
Fri Mar 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code>>

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

String.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", dt);
```